# Unable to create bean -- Autowire candidate is expected

Tags: java, spring

I have a batch project I'm attempting to deploy to a Tomcat 6.0 server. I'm using Maven as my build management tool, and the project builds without errors. However, once I attempt to deploy, I get the following error:

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'retrieveKeys': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.company.obc.idle.dao.PnetDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER)}
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />
<import resource="applicationContext-sql.xml"/>
<import resource="applicationContext-db.xml" />
<!-- <import resource="applicationContext-mq.xml" /> -->


<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.app.obc.idle" />
<!-- NEEDED FOR JAXB TO WORK -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />

<bean id="retrieveKeys" class="com.company.obc.idle.batch.RetrieveKeys" />

<bean id="jobProcessUnmarkedPTOEventKeysDetail"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="retrieveKeys" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="retrieveKeys" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>


<bean id="cronTriggerProcessUnmarkedPTOEventKeys" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobProcessUnmarkedPTOEventKeysDetail" />
    <!-- TEST -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/15 * * * * ?" />
    <!-- PROD
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 30 1/6 * * ?" /> -->
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTriggerProcessUnmarkedPTOEventKeys" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is the RetrieveKeys class that I am attempting to call using the quartz timer. I've tried a number of different things to get this to work, and this latest version has an attempt at naming the component to try and solve the problem:

```
    @Component(("retrieveKeys"))
    public class RetrieveKeys {

@Resource
PnetDAO PnetDAO;

@Resource
ProcessEvents ProcessEvents;

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RetrieveKeys.class);

    public void retrieveKeys() throws Exception{
        //SOME MORE CODE
```

I'll also include my DAO and its implementation. I'm wondering why this would be mentioned in the problem as there is another DAO class that is set up the same way, but it is not mentioned in the error.

```
public interface PnetDAO {

public abstract List<UnprocessedKeys> SelectUnprocessedEvents() throws Exception;
public abstract List<IdleEvent> SelectDetailedEventInformation(String uniqkey) throws Exception;
public abstract int UpdatePTOIdle(int statusFlag, String uniqKey) throws Exception;

}
```

...

```
@Repository
public class PnetDAOImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements PnetDAO {

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PnetDAOImpl.class);

@Resource(name = "queriesBean")
private Properties sql;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private Map<Class, RowMapper> rowMappers;

@Autowired
public PnetDAOImpl(@Qualifier("com.company.datasource.PNETPRD") DataSource ds){
    super();
    this.setDataSource(ds);
}

//ACCESSING DATA HERE
```

I'm confused why Spring would be looking at my DAO when I didn't mention it anywhere in the applicationContext file. Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What package are `RetrieveKeys` and `PnetDAOImpl` in?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: it's in com.company.obc.idle.dao (which is not in the scanned packages)

Comment: `RetrieveKeys` is in `com.company.obc.idle.batch` and `PnetDAOImpl` is in `com.company.obc.idle.dao`. I thought that since I used `<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.app.obc.idle" />` as the packages to scan, these would be included since they are below the main package.

Comment: Also note that the `@Autowired` constructor of `PnetDAOImpl` which uses a `@Qualifier` `value`  that may not be present in `applicationContext-db.xml`. That looks like a weird ID. But if you really have it, ignore me.

Comment: @Reese `app` vs `obc`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Well that's embarrassing! Unfortunately, that doesn't completely solve the problem, It still won't deploy.

Comment: @Reese See my comment above my last comment. If you still have errors, consider asking another question or posting the new stack trace by editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told Spring to autowire a PNetDAO instance in the RetrieveKeys component:

```
@Resource
PnetDAO PnetDAO;
```

So Spring tries to find a bean implementing this interface, doesn't find any, and thus throws the exception.

It doesn't find your implementing class because it's in the package `com.company.obc.idle.dao`, and you told Spring to scan classes from the package `com.company.app.obc.idle`.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that I didn't see that I was trying to specify a package that doesn't exist. I'm annotating PnetDAO as a resource because I call it later in the method
`int p = ProcessEvents.ProcessPTOKeys(uniqkeys.get(i).toString());`
Don't I need to have that there in order to make this work?

Comment: There's no problem in injecting the DAO. But the package name used in the spring config file must be fixed to make the injection work. Also, please respect the Java naming conventions to make your code readable: variables and methods start with a lower-case letter, and are camelCased.

Comment: Oh I see. That moved things along. Thanks for your help. Before I publish this thing, I'll be sure to change it to meet conventions...I should have been doing that from the start.